# Add a project with a static class to another project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

OK, this might be a pretty basic question so please sorry.

In Eclipse, I have a project with some utilities, let's call it Utils.
Something like

```
public class Utils {
   public static void doSomething() {
        // do something
   }
}
```

I want to use this project as a library for many my other projects, for example my project "MyProject"

After I assure that there are no syntax problems in Utils, I keep it open in the UI and open also MyProject.

In MyProject I go to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Add and add Utils.
Now I should be able to see Utils.doSomething() when I press CTRL-Space and use it in the code, but this is not the case.
What am I missing?
I have been going round and round to find how but could not find a solution.

Thank you very much

EDIT:
I think I tried all the usual problem-solving solutions like cleaning the projects, restarting Eclipse, recreating ex-novo Utils, rebuilding and automatic imports.
For this reason I think that the real problem is not Eclipse but me, I am missing something that I don't understand.

Comment: Try cleaning the project `Alt` + `P`, `N`

Comment: This was one of my first tries unfortunately :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it.
The Utils (Android) project had the public class in the "default container" that had no name, probably that was the reason.